# Scale of largest CPLEX/Gurobi execution

Tags: cplex, gurobi, computational-complexity, docplex, computational-experiments

I am trying to understand the CO2 emission of large scale optimization using CPLEX or Gurobi. Is there a published literature which addresses the compute usage of large scale executions?

Comment: Do you want to model how much C)O2 emissions are caused by running optimization problems, or do you want to use optimization to understand (optimize) CO2 emissions?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, the former one.